# Creating a JSON tree with specific keys and values by array of strings

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, reduce

I have an array of strings

```
["storage/", "storage/ui/", "storage/inventory/", "storage/model/", "storage/staticmos/", "storage/ui/server.js", "storage/ui/config.js", "storage/ui/elements/", "storage/ui/package.json", "storage/ui/model/", "storage/ui/gulpfile.js", "storage/ui/i18n/", "storage/ui/metadata/", "storage/ui/index.template.html"]
```

And my purpose is to make a json tree in which every object will contain next properties: `name` (name of directory/name of file), `type`(file or directory), `path` (the actual array entry), `id`, `children` (only if the type is directory! empty array if there is nothing in a directory)

So the returned value should look like this:

```
[
            {
              id: 1,
              name: "Inventory",
              type: "directory",
              path: "../../elements/storage/Inventory",
              children: [
                {
                  id: 2,
                  name: "inventory.yaml",
                  type: "file",
                  path: "../../elements/storage/Inventory/inventory.yaml",
                },
              ],
            },
            {
              id: 3,
              name: "UI",
              type: "directory",
              path: "../../elements/storage/UI",
              children: [
                {
                  id: 4,
                  name: "Model",
                  type: "directory",
                  path: "../../elements/storage/UI/Model",
                  children: [
                    {
                      id: 5,
                      name: "viewmodel",
                      type: "directory",
                      path: "../../elements/storage/UI/Model/viewmodel",
                      children: [],
                    },
                  ],
                },
                {
                  id: 6,
                  name: "elements",
                  type: "directory",
                  path: "../../elements/storage/elements",
                  children: [],
                },
                {
                  id: 7,
                  name: "i18n",
                  type: "directory",
                  path: "../../elements/storage/i18n",
                  children: [],
                },
                {
                  id: 8,
                  name: "index.template.html",
                  type: "file",
                  path: "../../elements/storage/index.template.html",
                },
              ],
            },
            {
              id: 9,
              name: "DeviceConnector",
              type: "directory",
              path: "../../elements/storage/DeviceConnector",
              children: [],
            },
          ]
```

So, I have 2 big problems right now:

1. returning after reduce operation object with specific keys
2. differentiating file from directory.

This is what I got for now:

```
   createObject([...pathes]) {
    return pathes.reduce((obj, path) => {
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-return-assign
      path.split('/').reduce((obj, key) => {"id":'_' + Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 9),"name":obj[key],"path":path} , obj);
      return obj;
    }, []);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could utilize the last slash and use it for changing the type.

```js
const
    data = ["storage/", "storage/ui/", "storage/inventory/", "storage/model/", "storage/staticmos/", "storage/ui/server.js", "storage/ui/config.js", "storage/ui/elements/", "storage/ui/package.json", "storage/ui/model/", "storage/ui/gulpfile.js", "storage/ui/i18n/", "storage/ui/metadata/", "storage/ui/index.template.html"],
    result = data.reduce((r, path) => {
        path.split('\/').reduce((level, name) => {
            if (name === '') {
                level.type = 'directory';
                return;
            }
            let directory = (level.children = level.children || []).find(q => q.name === name);
            if (!directory) level.children.push(directory = { id: '_' + Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 9), name, type: 'file', path });
            return directory;
        }, r);
        return r;
    }, {}).children;

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thank you Nina for your help! could u please explain what does "??=" ?

Comment: it is the [logical nullish assignment `??=`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_nullish_assignment).

Comment: Is it possible to refactor this string :             let directory = (level.children ??= []).find(q => q.name === name) somehow? my editor can't compile it

Comment: Thank you so much! need some more practice with this - can recommend some typical tasks for it to practice more?

Comment: and how does this work             let directory = (level.children = level.children || []).find(q => q.name === name) ?

Comment: the part `level.children = level.children || []` assigns `level.children`, if this value is [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy), like an array or ([logical OR `||`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_OR)) the array literately.

Comment: Nina, please explain, why do we `return r` ?

Comment: `r` is the accumulator and for the next iteration it needs to be returned.